# Trace function is not working in Actionscript 3 Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I recently upgraded to Flash CS6, and now my trace statements in Actionscript 3 are not writing to the output window.

If I create a simple document with this Actionscript...

```
trace("test!");
```

...I get no results in the output window. I don't know why this is happening. Is this a bug?

And I have researched this, and I can tell you this:

1. I'm just publishing locally and this is still happening.
2. I'm publish previewing to Flash, not HTML
3. In the publish settings tab,  "omit trace actions" is unchecked
4. In the Output panel, I have tried all options for filter (from nothing to "none" to verbose)

I'm pretty sure it was working, and then stopped.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you don't have the flash player debugger anymore ? Double check by right clicking on your flashplayer window, and see the option "Debugger" and "Show redraw regions"

Comment: Hmmm... When I right-click on my flashplayer window, I don't get any options that look like those.

Comment: I've now updated to the debug version, and updated Flash CS6 to the latest version of both the player and the software. Nothing. No trace statements show up in the Output console.

Comment: Reading better your question, seems you are PUBLISHING (f12), when you should have used Ctrl + ENTER (Control > Test Movie).
If you are really publishing (outside of the Flash IDE), the Output Panel will never shows anything.

Comment: Marcelo. That's right. I figured that out. But what really throws me is that in CS5, when I published using the same keystrokes or menu-commands, it used to keep it in the Flash IDE. I noticed that when I went back to CS5 and tried it. I wonder why the change. Thanks to both of you for your input!  I appreciate it.